# LiveAgent Rest API set timeout

Tags: liveagent

Is there a way to set the session timeout for rest requests of LiveAgent API?
By default it's set to 30 seconds and it is very small amount of time to complete all required request to send a message to agent ( I'm trying to test API manually through Apegee Console / curl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set time out.

In Live agent Rest API document (page 4) it is mentioned as:

> If you don’t receive a response within the number of seconds indicated
>   by the clientPollTimeout property in your SessionId request, your
>   network connection to the server is likely experiencing an error, so
>   you should terminate the request

You can only get the timeout property (`clientPollTimeout`) from session Id request.